# Unpartitioned exfat 5tb disk recovery: testdisk shows really strange results

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk, exfat

I apologize because this is a bit general in nature. I have a 5TB external disk that was formatted exfat. I would use it to backup data from my Linux machine. Well, recently, I plugged it into a windows 10 machine and windows 10 just ignored it. I ran it through `testdisk` and this is where it's at so far:

[image: testdisk results so far]

I'm thinking if I just repartition the drive and not format it and then use testdisk to recover the data on it then that would be sufficient. Any HDD gurus out there able to give any other suggestions?

Comment: I assume you have no other backups?

Comment: You guessed it. :\ I'm fairly confident I can get what I need off this drive. I'm just curious what the best way to go about it is.